# Eclipse command line formatter on non eclipse Java code

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line, formatting

So I've been using the eclipse command line formatter to keep my co-workers code and mine in the same format, and it works great!  When it works.  The problem is it only seems to work when I try to format a Java file that is within an eclipse project.  Standalone Java files simply don't get formatted.  The formatter runs without error, but the format of the file does not change.  The command looks like this:

eclipse -application org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter -vm (dir/Java/jre) -config (myconffile) myfile.java

Comment: I've never heard of running the formatter as a standalone, but have you looked at the Eclipse logfile? `${WORKSPACE}/.metadata/.log` (where `${WORKSPACE}` is your workspace base directory). Also, what is the `-vm` option for? I don't think it does what you think it does...

Comment: Yes but it does not seen to contain any information on the command line executions.

Comment: The -verbose option should give you an idea of what the problem is.

Comment: Have you tried it?  For me, the verbose option literally does nothing.  I'm using Powershell 4 personally...  But the formatter never outputs anything even with verbose...

Answer (score 0):

As dcsolh points out, your command line is incorrectly formatted - the `-vm` parameter is out of place and should have a following argument giving the location of the JVM.

Have you tried using the `-verbose` option to see exactly what's happening as the formatter runs? Also, you may need to specify a formatter configuration file, as [described in the online help](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-231.htm). Basically, you can export formatter settings out of Eclipse to a file, then use the `-config` parameter to point the standalone formatter to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  So actually that was just a mistake with my post, i was encoding some parameters with Lt,GT signs and they didn't show up..  But this command works on Java files in eclipse projects, so the syntax is right..